# ¿Como mostrar los datos de una tabla en codelgniter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

al momento de cargar mis datos en mi vista no me parece nada

les dejo mi controlador

```
public function ver(){
    $data = array(
        'enlaces' => $this->Usuario_model->verCita()
    );
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}
```

mi modelo

```
function verCita(){
    $query = $this->db->get('eventos');
    if ($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

y mi vista

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/img/uni.ico">
    <title>Calendario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/fullcalendar.css" />
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <style>
        .Formato{
            background: green;
            color:#ffffff;
            border-radius: 20px; 
        }
            .Formato2{
            background: red;
            color:#ffffff;
            border-radius: 20px; 
        }
    </style>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
            events:[
                  <?php
                     foreach($enlaces->result() as $fila ) {
                  ?>
                     {  

                        id:"<?php echo $fila["title"];?>",
                        title:"<?php echo $fila["title"];?>",
                        start:"<?php echo $fila["start"];?>",
                        end:"<?php echo $fila["end"];?>",
                        url:"<?php echo $fila["url"];?>",
                        className:"<?php echo $fila["className"];?>",
                        editable:"<?php echo $fila["editable"];?>"

                     },
            <?php
               }
            ?>
        ]               
        })
    });  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1> <center> Calendario de sala de juntas </center> </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="calendario"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar lo que aparece si haces un `print_r($enlaces->result())` o `print_r($fila)` ?

Comment: en el modelo agrega `return $query->result();`

Answer (score 0):

El controlador que utilizas;

```
public function ver(){
    $data = array(
        'enlaces' => $this->Usuario_model->verCita()
    );
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}
```

Recoje los datos de la función **vercita()** y lo que recoge lo vuelca sobre la vista en la variable **$data**, por tanto en la vista deberías de recorrer este array a través del array **$data**.

Es decir tendrías que utilizar en la vista la variable de forma que quede así;

```
public function ver(){
    $data = array(
        'enlaces' => $this->Usuario_model->verCita()
    );
    **$this->load->view('login_view', $data);**
}
```

Si aún así sigues sin encontrar datos, comprueba que la función del modelo recoge correctamente los datos que quieres mostrar.

Espero que esto te ayude un saludo.